# Tengo problemas al pasar un archivo HTML-CSS

Tags: html, css

El problema es más que nada con las imágenes, están con url en los archivos .css. Al guardar todo el proyecto en un archivo .rar y pasarlo a otra computadora, en esa computadora a la que fue transferida el archivo, no le cargan las imágenes y no encuentro la forma de hacer que no se desconfiguren.

Comment: Hola y bienvenid@. Te sugiero hacer [el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que conozcas las normas del sitio respecto a las publicaciones.

Comment: Es fácil: agrega la carpeta de las imágenes dentro del archivo del proyecto para que, cuando se comprima el proyecto, también se incluyan las imagenes. Aunque esto seria mas pesado y lento, es la unica forma. O si la url esta online, no habria problemas

Comment: Pues cojes y editas los archivos CSS y le cambias las url completas por relativas. Es decir, donde ponga `https://www.midominio.com/imagenes/img1.jpg` lo cambias por `/imagenes/img1.jpg`, quitándole la ruta que ya no está, que es la del dominio, y en ese momento pasarán a ser referencias relativas y deberían volver a aparecer (eso si no has puesto el proyecto en una subcarpeta nueva o distinta a la original, en cuyo caso debes afinar esa referencia relativa para que cuadre). Y eso solo en las urls que sean del dominio antiguo, si hay otras imágenes externas déjalas sin cambiar.